# How to populate a dropdown from API in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a code that populate a dropdown with values from an API, which seems not working correctly, the dropdown is inside the reactive form named detailsForm, below is HTML and TypeScript code:

```html
<div>
  <select
    class="form-select text-warning"
    formControlName="medecinsSelect"
    id="medecinsSelect"
    aria-label="Medecins"
  >
    <option
      *ngFor="let inscription of inscriptions; let i = index"
      [value]="inscriptions[i].medecinId"
      >{{ inscriptions[i].medecin.nom }}</option
    >
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createDetailsForm();
    this.loadInscriptionsForPatient();
    console.log(this.detailsForm.value);
  }

  createDetailsForm() {
    this.detailsForm = this.fb.group({
      medecinsSelect: ['']
    });
  }

  loadInscriptionsForPatient() {
    this.patientService.getPatientInscriptions(this.patient.id).subscribe(
      (insc: Inscription[]) => {
        this.inscriptions = insc;
        this.detailsForm.controls.medecinsSelect.patchValue(this.inscriptions[0].medecinId);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

In the `DOM` I can see the options values, but when I try to see the selected value using `console.log(this.detailsForm.get('medecinsSelect').value);` it gives the value as empty.
Any help on this please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where do you try to log the value?

Comment: inside ngOnInit() after this.loadInscriptionsForPatient()